# doxygen called/caller graph

Tags: doxygen

Following snipet from the doxygen log shows that the caller/called graph from vs 2008 C# code are generated but I dont see any link to them from index.html . Where is full graph from the main function located ?

Generating caller graph for function xyz

Answer (score 1):

index.html points to a class list, annotated.html in my case. This html lists classes that links for example to class_*myclass*.html, and this then links to the generated image.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation page for the `xyz` function. It should contain the caller graph.